# Algorithm for Compare Paragraph with the array of keywords in php

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, logic

I want to develop the quiz system for the subjective paper. In this system user can answer the question in paragraph rather than selecting from multiple choice. Admin can add the question with the number of keywords as a answer. I want a effective algorithm to compare a user answer (max 100 words) with the pre defined array of keywords (max 50 words). How can I implement this? please help me.

thanks in Advance!
I am thinking to convert the user paragraph into array of words , than compare with array of pre-defined keywords. But I think this is the time consuming approach to implement this system. 
For example, If user answer array contain 100 words and pre-defined array contain 50 words then 100*50 comparison, this is too much costly.

please help me to find the effective solution preferably in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to split the text into words you must do the algo for each language individually. You'll face with a problem that splitting the text with spaces is not enough for your task: punctuation is still here. So you have to save `-` and trim `!`, `,`, `!`, etc chars. At the same time if you look at Chinese language you may see that they use another set of punctuation chars so you have to enumerate them all.

   However it's easy to solve this task with a [str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) method and with a small help of predefined alphabet. The example below works with English text (without extra alphabet) and with Greek text (with an alphabet):

```php
function words($string, $charlist = null)
{
    return str_word_count($string, 1, $charlist);
}


$string_ASCII = 'ASCII string example'; # string(20) "ASCII string example"

$result = words($string_ASCII); # Array
                                # (
                                #     [0] => ASCII
                                #     [1] => string
                                #     [2] => example
                                # )


$string_UTF8 = 'UTF-8 string πράδειγμα'; # string(31) "UTF-8 string πράδειγμα"

$alphabet = '1234567890-ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩαάβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω';

$result = words($string_UTF8, $alphabet); # Array
                                          # (
                                          #     [0] => UTF-8
                                          #     [1] => string
                                          #     [2] => πράδειγμα
                                          # )
```

2. You don't need to compare 2 arrays again and again. Use indexing. The best idea is to use [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) on your array of keywords and then iterate through the user words only once and check the word with isset:

```php
$keywords = array_flip($keywords); # $keywords - your 50 words

$words = words($string); # $string - a text with 100 words from user

foreach ($words as $word)
{
    # only 100 iterations with fast isset validation

    if (isset($keywords[$word]))
    {
        # it exists!
    }
}
```

3. It's also a good idea to think about word normalization because user may use `legs` when you have a `leg` in your keyword list which is correct too. For English language I may recommend next one code:

```php
# Author - https:#gist.github.com/tbrianjones
# Source - https:#gist.github.com/tbrianjones/ba0460cc1d55f357e00b
#
# The MIT License (MIT)
#
# Copyright (c) 2015
#
#
# Changes:
#   Removed rule for virus -> viri
#   Added rule for potato -> potatoes
#   Added rule for *us -> *uses

class english
{
    private static $plural = array
    (
        '/(quiz)$/i'                     => '$1zes',
        '/^(ox)$/i'                      => '$1en',
        '/([m|l])ouse$/i'                => '$1ice',
        '/(matr|vert|ind)ix|ex$/i'       => '$1ices',
        '/(x|ch|ss|sh)$/i'               => '$1es',
        '/([^aeiouy]|qu)y$/i'            => '$1ies',
        '/(hive)$/i'                     => '$1s',
        '/(?:([^f])fe|([lr])f)$/i'       => '$1$2ves',
        '/(shea|lea|loa|thie)f$/i'       => '$1ves',
        '/sis$/i'                        => 'ses',
        '/([ti])um$/i'                   => '$1a',
        '/(tomat|potat|ech|her|vet)o$/i' => '$1oes',
        '/(bu)s$/i'                      => '$1ses',
        '/(alias)$/i'                    => '$1es',
        '/(octop)us$/i'                  => '$1i',
        '/(ax|test)is$/i'                => '$1es',
        '/(us)$/i'                       => '$1es',
        '/s$/i'                          => 's',
        '/$/'                            => 's'
    );

    private static $singular = array
    (
        '/(quiz)zes$/i'              => '$1',
        '/(matr)ices$/i'             => '$1ix',
        '/(vert|ind)ices$/i'         => '$1ex',
        '/^(ox)en$/i'                => '$1',
        '/(alias)es$/i'              => '$1',
        '/(octop|vir)i$/i'           => '$1us',
        '/(cris|ax|test)es$/i'       => '$1is',
        '/(shoe)s$/i'                => '$1',
        '/(o)es$/i'                  => '$1',
        '/(bus)es$/i'                => '$1',
        '/([m|l])ice$/i'             => '$1ouse',
        '/(x|ch|ss|sh)es$/i'         => '$1',
        '/(m)ovies$/i'               => '$1ovie',
        '/(s)eries$/i'               => '$1eries',
        '/([^aeiouy]|qu)ies$/i'      => '$1y',
        '/([lr])ves$/i'              => '$1f',
        '/(tive)s$/i'                => '$1',
        '/(hive)s$/i'                => '$1',
        '/(li|wi|kni)ves$/i'         => '$1fe',
        '/(shea|loa|lea|thie)ves$/i' => '$1f',
        '/(^analy)ses$/i'            => '$1sis',
        '/((a)naly|(b)a|(d)iagno|(p)arenthe|(p)rogno|(s)ynop|(t)he)ses$/i' => '$1$2sis',
        '/([ti])a$/i'                => '$1um',
        '/(n)ews$/i'                 => '$1ews',
        '/(h|bl)ouses$/i'            => '$1ouse',
        '/(corpse)s$/i'              => '$1',
        '/(us)es$/i'                 => '$1',
        '/s$/i'                      => ''
    );

    private static $irregular = array
    (
        'move'   => 'moves',
        'foot'   => 'feet',
        'goose'  => 'geese',
        'sex'    => 'sexes',
        'child'  => 'children',
        'man'    => 'men',
        'tooth'  => 'teeth',
        'person' => 'people'
    );

    private static $uncountable = array
    (
        'sheep',
        'fish',
        'deer',
        'series',
        'species',
        'money',
        'rice',
        'information',
        'equipment'
    );

    public static function pluralize($string)
    {
        # save some time in the case that singular and plural are the same
        if (in_array(mb_strtolower($string), self::$uncountable))
        {
            return $string;
        }


        # check for irregular singular forms
        foreach (self::$irregular as $pattern => $result)
        {
            $pattern = '/' . $pattern . '$/i';

            if (preg_match($pattern, $string))
            {
                return preg_replace($pattern, $result, $string);
            }
        }

        # check for matches using regular expressions
        foreach (self::$plural as $pattern => $result)
        {
            if (preg_match($pattern, $string))
            {
                return preg_replace($pattern, $result, $string);
            }
        }

        return $string;
    }

    public static function singularize($string)
    {
        # save some time in the case that singular and plural are the same
        if (in_array(mb_strtolower($string), self::$uncountable))
        {
            return $string;
        }

        # check for irregular plural forms
        foreach (self::$irregular as $result => $pattern)
        {
            $pattern = '/' . $pattern . '$/i';

            if (preg_match($pattern, $string))
            {
                return preg_replace($pattern, $result, $string);
            }
        }

        # check for matches using regular expressions
        foreach (self::$singular as $pattern => $result)
        {
            if (preg_match($pattern, $string))
            {
                return preg_replace($pattern, $result, $string);
            }
        }

        return $string;
    }
}
```

4. You may also use `$words = array_unique($words)` right after transforming text into the words if you want to remove duplicates from the user input (it may solve the problem if you have `legs` in your keyword list and user used it 100 times to get 100 points). Also it will make your code a bit faster because less words = less iterations in the loop after it :)

Comment: Thank you so much friend :-) you made my day. I will implement according to your suggestion and if i feel any difficulty or need any help, can I contact you? if yes, kindly share your email here in comments.
once again, thank you very much for the help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

- keep your keywords array sorted
- once user submits an answer: keep only unique words along with counts
- now you can go through each unique word in the answer and do a binary search against sorted array of keywords. If match - increase by stored count

Checking complexity will be `O(number_of_unique_answer_keywords * log(keywords) * avg(string_length))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) or [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) functions within PHP to compare your two arrays for exact and close matches